# Программа, написанная на Qt 5.1.1, по-разному ведёт себя на Windows 8 и 7

Tags: windows, qt5, qt, c++, visual-c++

Доброго времени суток!
Есть программа, написанная на Qt 5.1.1 на машине Windows 8 x64 c применением компилятора VC++ 2010 (x86). В программе для создания интерфейса использован QtQuick 2.0 и QtQml.Models 2.1 - другие версии выбрать нельзя. Программа спокойно запускается и работает на Windows 8 (x64), а на 7 (x86) - запускается, но отображается только пустая форма. В чём может быть проблема? Все необходимые dll есть рядом с exe-файлом приложения.

**UPD:** любое приложение Qt с использованием QtQuick 2.0 не запускается на Windows 7 x86.

Comment: да с Qt5.1.x у меня тоже что-то непонятное, правда пишу под линуксом. Может ещё сырое просто?

Comment: я не так давно с ним работаю, так что ещё не разобрался во всех причудах) где бы теперь самую последнюю стабильную версию найти?

Comment: интрефейс как в программу попадает? Через qrc, в c++ генерите, в рядом файлике лежит? Не  может он по каким-то причинам просто не находить его?

Comment: @aknew, да, интерфейс лежит в qrc, файл находится в той же директории, что и .h и .cpp-файлы проекта. Может, я как-то коряво подключаю его к коду на С++, но ведь в одной системе всё работает. Сейчас попробовал собрать проект, который идёт в комплекте с Qt - Analog clock и он спокойно заработал на Win 7. Единственное, там нет интерфейса на QtQuick.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Как обычно и бывает - решение нашёл сам.
Итак, как вы знаете, для того чтобы приложение на Qt работало вне IDE, нам необходимо либо статически собрать нашу версию Qt, либо аккуратно сложить все необходимые dll в папке с исполняемым файлом приложения. Я изначально выбрал второй путь, поэтому директория приложения выглядела следующим образом:

```
- D3DCompiler_43.dll
- icudt51.dll
- icuin51.dll
- icuuc51.dll
- libEGL.dll
- libGLESv2.dll
- Qt5Core.dll
- Qt5Gui.dll
- Qt5Network.dll
- Qt5Qml.dll
- Qt5Quick.dll
- Qt5V8.dll
- Qt5Widgets.dll
- app.exe
- platforms/qminimal.dll
- platforms/qoffscreen.dll
- platforms/qwindows.dll
```

Казалось бы, ведь есть уже **Qt5Qml.dll** и **Qt5Quick.dll**, которые должны отвечать за работу с QtQuick, но не тут-то было. После долгого гугления выяснилось, что состав директории должен быть дополнен каталогами *QtQml* и *QtQuick.2*. После чего всё прекрасно заработало. Спасибо за внимание, вопрос удалять не буду, а просто закрою - вдруг кому понадобится.